# Append TimeStamp to a File Name

Tags: c#, .net, file, datetime, file-io

I have come across this problem several times in which I would like to have multiple versions of the same file in the same directory. The way I have been doing it using C# is by adding a time stamp to the file name with something like this `DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '.')`. 
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 313, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")`

or [string.Format](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

`string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss-fff}", DateTime.Now)`;

or [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings)

`$"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss-fff}"`

> There are following custom format specifiers y (year), M (month), d
>   (day), h (hour 12), H (hour 24), m (minute), s (second), f (second
>   fraction), F (second fraction, trailing zeroes are trimmed), t (P.M or
>   A.M) and z (time zone).

**With Extension Method**

Usage:

```
string result = "myfile.txt".AppendTimeStamp();
//myfile20130604234625642.txt
```

Extension method

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string AppendTimeStamp(this string fileName)
    {
        return string.Concat(
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"),
            Path.GetExtension(fileName)
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added `Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)` to get the full path to the file. Then replaced `string.Concat()`with `Path.Combine()` the get the full filename.

Answer (score 22):

I prefer to use:

```
string result = "myFile_" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".txt";
```

What does ToFileTime() do?

> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to a Windows file time.
>
> `public long ToFileTime()`
>
> A Windows file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). Windows uses a file time to record when an application creates, accesses, or writes to a file.

Source: [MSDN documentation - DateTime.ToFileTime Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps appending `DateTime.Now.Ticks` instead, is a tiny bit faster since you won't be creating 3 strings and the ticks value will always be unique also.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
```

Comment: this answer the way you get the timestamp!. append it to a file using the Path class and string manipulation is not an issue at all. this only an alternative to DateTime.ToString Method (String) or string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}",DateTime.Now);

Answer (score 1):

You can use below instead:

```
DateTime.Now.Ticks
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the answer from maf-soft I created my own solution, which can handle Pathes too.

So these are the unittests I use:

```
Assert.Test(new MyPathTools().AppendTimeStamp(@"AnyFile.pdf", new FakeMyDateTime("15.2.2021 15:23:17")), 
                                              @"AnyFile20210215152317.pdf");
Assert.Test(new MyPathTools().AppendTimeStamp(@"C:\Temp\Test\", new FakeMyDateTime("15.2.2021 15:23:17")), 
                                              @"C:\Temp\Test\20210215152317");
Assert.Test(new MyPathTools().AppendTimeStamp(@"C:\Temp\Test\AnyFile.pdf", new FakeMyDateTime("15.2.2021 15:23:17")), 
                                              @"C:\Temp\Test\AnyFile20210215152317.pdf");
```

The code (for copy&paste) looks like this:

```
public class MyPathTools 
{
    public string AppendTimeStamp(string fileName)
    {
        return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), string.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
                                                                           DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"),
                                                                           Path.GetExtension(fileName))
            );
    }
}
```

The code that works with my Framework (and is unittestable) looks like this:

```
public class MyPathTools : IMyPathTools
{
    public string AppendTimeStamp(string fileName, IMyDateTime myDateTime)
    {
        return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), string.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
                                                                           myDateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"),
                                                                           Path.GetExtension(fileName))
                );
    }
}
```