# Return a JavaScript type date in C#

Tags: c#, javascript

`Date.parse(new Date())` code in javascript will return example value:`1373872659000`

I want the above code convert to  C# Code can get the same value as javascript ,Please Help.
I had  the following code.But return different value.

```
public static double ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0, 0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan diff = date.ToUniversalTime() - origin;
    return Math.Floor(diff.TotalMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Hint it is number of milliseconds from Jan 1 1970

Comment: please specify what you want to and what you have tried and what is the problem

Comment: @Sayse please corect me if you try my code

Comment: @raman i want same value return as javascript return in C#

Comment: You haven't said what is wrong (what different value)(removed downvote). The math.Floor seems pointless btw

Comment: as you can see the C# code i post.i pass in DateTime.Today.Date. but the value not same with javascipt return out.

Comment: I think you just want to add the timestamp if yes then 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892074/function-that-creates-a-timestamp-in-c-sharp


or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898392/append-timestamp-to-a-file-name

Comment: `DateTime.Today` (and `.Date`) has 00:00:00 as time. I assume the JavaScript `new Date()` does have the current. Try `DateTime.UtcNow`. Or you could try if JS `Date.parse(new Date(2013, 7, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0))` will give you the same as your C# `ConvertToTimestamp(new DateTime(2013, 7, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc))`.

Comment: Timestamp in milliseconds also calculate hours:mins:secs difference. So, How you said both function run same time? Try this to See - http://www.timestampconvert.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using

```
DateTime dat = DateTime.Parse(Date);
var milli = dat.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(
     new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

**Updates:**

```
public static double ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime date)
        {
            DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            DateTime d2 = date.ToUniversalTime();
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);
            return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
```